# Калькулятор на js с множеством аргументов

Tags: javascript

Дали такое задание:

> Создать калькулятор, где будет только поле для введния значений. Одна кнопка для расчета выражений. Калькулятор считает только +,-,*,/. Но выражение может содержать любое количество аргументов.

Пришла к выводу, что здесь можно использовать eval, но как правильно это прописать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `eval`, вообще говоря, очень не рекомендуется, однако в данном случае, это, пожалуй, всё же можно сделать достаточно безопасно:

```js
function calc() {
  let res;
  let expr = document.getElementById('inp').value;
  if (/^[\d\s+\-*/().]*$/.test(expr)) { // проверка, чтобы не было введено ничего лишнего
    try {
      res = eval(expr);
    } catch (e) {
      res = 'Невозможно вычислить!'
    }
  } else {
    res = 'Введены недопустимые символы!';
  }
  showResult(res);

}

function showResult(res) {
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = res;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text"></input>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="calculate"></input>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Но надо подчеркнуть, что это решение работает только для приведённых в вопросе условий, и очень плохо масштабируется при изменении этих самых условий (например, если внезапно понадобится добавить вычисление квадратного корня, то сразу придётся прикручивать очень неудобоваримые костыли).
Более правильный же путь — это распарсить введённое выражение и вычислить его самостоятельно. В этом может помочь [Алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: Круто, спасибо! На данном этапе просто еще до такого не дошли и нужно было самое простое и незатейливое решение